# how to create a custom message in ROSJava

Tags: ros, nxt, messages, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create my own messages using rosjava but I don't know how to create it.

Example:

```
JointCommand.msg
string name
float64 effort
```

Later, how to set and get data from that message?

Currently, I know how to create simple messages and get data:

```
org.ros.message.std_msgs.String str = new org.ros.message.std_msgs.String();
str.data = "" + seq;
```

How to create a future complex message: JointCommand

Many thanks in advance.

Juan Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12540/how-to-create-a-custom-message-in-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently rosjava requires all .msg/.srv files to be defined externally and included as dependencies in the manifest file.  I believe this was done to promote separation of msg packages and the packages that use them.  Any packages included in the manifest will prompt java JAR generation for those foreign message types.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3